# Function error: double[] to double?

Tags: c, compiler-errors

I'm having an issues with an assignment. I've spent the last hour trying to figure it out.  I don't see any syntax errors personally.

This is the error

> Error 1   error C2440: 'function' : cannot convert from 'double [49]' to 'double'

This is the line its referring to:

```
std_report(student_id, upexp_m, upexp_y, upinc_m, upinc_y, num);
```

With the declarations:

```
int student_id[MAX];
double upexp_m[MAX], upexp_y[MAX], upinc_m[MAX], upinc_y[MAX];

void std_report(int student_id[], double exp_m[], double exp_[], double income_m, double income_y, int size);
```

And the implementation:

```
void std_report(int student_id[], double exp_m[], double exp_y[], double income_m[], double income_y[], int size) {
  printf("\n\n<STUDENT NAME> Budget Report (Student ID:%d\n", student_id[size]);
  printf("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\n");
  printf("Expenses\n~~~~~~~~\n\n");
  printf("%45c MONTHLY %6c ANNUALLY\n", ' ', ' ');
  printf("Total Expenses: %28c $ %.2lf %5c $ %.2lf\n", ' ', exp_m[size], ' ', exp_y[size]);
  printf("Total Income: %30c $ %.2lf %5c $ %.2lf\n", ' ',income_m[size], ' ',income_y[size]);
  printf("Total Savings Available for your goals: %4c $ %.2lf %6c $ %.2lf\n\n\n", ' ', income_m[size]-exp_m[size], ' ', income_y[size]-exp_y[size]);
  return;
}
```

If there is anything else I can paste let me know, I'm completely stumped.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

### Solution

There was a `[]` missing in prototype.

Comment: lets see the declarations of student_id, upexp_m, upexp_y, upinc_m, and upinc_y

Comment: Can we see the declaration of epexp_m, upexp_y and so on?  Also, if you're only going to use one of the values from an array, there's no point to have a function take in the entire array.  Just have it take in the one value.  Oh, and if num == the length of the array, arr[size] is invalid.  arr[size-1] is the last valid access.

Comment: Have you declared `std_report` somewhere independently from the implementation? Maybe you forgot a `[]` there?

Comment: I think @bitmask nailed it.  Can you also add the declaration of std_report?

Comment: Also you might as well make the parameters pointers, since the arrays will decay anyway.

Comment: Lol silly noob I am.  I left out 2 pairs of [] in the function prototype.  I thought it didn't matter though.

Comment: From void std_report(int student_id[], double exp_m[], double exp_[], double income_m, double income_y, int size);

Comment: @crashez Curious why you would think the difference between a double and an array of doubles didn't matter ... especially when the error message referred to exactly that. Take a close look at Corbin's comment, because it zeroes in on what may be your confusion.

Answer (score 1):

An analytical way to approach this: Look at the error, it clearly states that your compiler is trying to convert something that is an array of `double`s (`double[49]`) to one ordinary `double`.

If we look at your `std_report` function, you are using all relevant variables with an array subscript, so the error cannot be there, your compiler also indicates that the error occurs at the line where you call `std_report`. Since, the variables you are passing as arguments have the correct type, the compiler must be under the assumption that one of the parameters has a different type.

Thus we have to check all points where you communicate to the compiler the desired parameter list for `std_report`, which is the **implementation and *all* declarations**.

Comment: Actually, the implementation is irrelevant. The only thing that matters is the prototype that is in scope at the point of the call.

Comment: @JimBalter: You could have *no explicit declaration* if the function was local to a compilation unit. So -- systematically -- you would have to check that the (implicit) declaration given by the implementation. That's why I included it. In this particular case, you are right, because we can determine from the OP that the parameter list of the implementation is correct.

Comment: I don't know I added the [] to the prototype which were missing and it functions properly now...

Comment: Again, the implementation is *irrelevant* ... compiler errors are based on the prototype in scope, explicitly or, implicitly, `int std_report()`. The only time that the implementation is relevant is when in occurs in the same file, before the call, and thus serves as the prototype.

Comment: @crashez: Great :) I just added a proper answer to sum up the solution and provide a blueprint for solving this class of errors. If you think your problem is thereby solved, you can accept an answer to indicate that.

Comment: @JimBalter: Exactly. That is was I was talking about. Of course you can say that "checking all delcarations" includes checking the implicit declaration provided by the implementation. Nonetheless, I thought I would explicitly mention it, since (especially for a somebody new to the C programming language) it could be easy to forget to check that declaration, too.

Comment: The prototype provided by the implementation -- that is, the definition -- is **explicit**, not **implicit**. The only thing that is implicit the `int std_report()` declaration used if no prototype is in scope. Again (and again and again) there is no need to check the function definition if it isn't being used as the prototype, because it has no bearing on how the compiler treats the call. Of course, it is important that the definition is consistent, else you get undefined behavior ... that's why all extern functions should have prototypes in header files and warnings should be enabled.

Comment: @JimBalter: I tend to use "implementation" and "definition" of functions interchangeably. By defining a function you implicitly declare it at the same time, don't you? Of course, I am *not* talking about the function body!